# Is Nagle's Algorithm the only algorithm with the same use?

Tags: algorithm, packet, nagle

Just asking, does anyone know if Nagle's Algorithm is the only algorithm that is use in packet sending? Are there any other algorithms that's the same like Nagle's? And if there aren't any, has Nagle's Algorithm been improved over the years? Thanks and sending sources to me would be very helpful.

Comment: Define "packet sending": ie. TCP

Comment: yes, TCP, I think. To be honest I'm still not quite sure how Nagle works. I'm still studying if there are any other algorithms like Nagle's Algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

As with any non-trivial program, the TCP stack employs a large number of "algorithms". Possibly the most interesting are the [congestion-avoidance algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion-avoidance_algorithm), which have been refined over the years, but which are still essentially based on the [Van Jacobson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Jacobson) slow-start algorithm.

Nagle's algorithm -- which is really more of a heuristic -- is an attempt to make TCP traffic more efficient by delaying the send of small packets until a reasonable amount of data can be sent. "Badly-written" applications may send a few bytes at a time, which causes massive overhead on the TCP connection, since there every TCP packet includes a TCP header as well as an IP header and a header for the low-level on-the-wire transmission protocol. All of these headers add up, and in the case of a data packet containing only a few bytes, the headers add up to far more than the data.

Unfortunately, not only badly-written applications exhibit this behaviour. A large class of applications need to deal with human beings and our impatience to see what we're doing. When you type a few characters into an ssh session, you expect that the remote machine will immediately receive the characters and start working on them. This can be particularly important if the character typed is an interrupt character. So in those cases, even though there will be transmission overhead, it is important to send the data right away. Consequently, the Nagle algorithm can be disabled on a connection by setting the `TCP_NODELAY` option. (Don't do this unless you need it.)

The classic reference on TCP is the *TCP Illustrated* series written by [Richard Stevens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Richard_Stevens) in the 1990s. Despite the passage of time, the books are still essential reading for anyone interested in understanding internet transmission protocols, which I suppose is an indication that the fundamental algorithms mostly remain intact.